# Git: clone repo and all branches custom function in .zshrc profile

Tags: regex, git, zsh

I'm new to zsh and git and am trying to write a function to stick in my zsh profile to clone a given repo along with all branches in the repo. So far I have

```sh
cloneAllBranches () { 
  repoName=$1

  git clone repoName

  dirName=$(echo "$repoName" | sed -E 's/^https:\/\/www\.github\.com\/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)\.git$/\2/')

  cd dirName

  for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master `; do
    git branch --track ${branch#remotes/origin/} $branch
  done
}
```

**Currently my dirName Regex returns the full clone path, not just the dir name.** New to zsh regex so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Also, I'm on a Mac.

Comment: You forgot to expand the repository name: `git clone "$repoName"` and the directory name: `cd "$dirName"`.

Comment: Can you post the value of repoName? The default URL that github offers you will not have the `www` subdomain, so this might be why your pattern isn't matching.

Comment: Meta advice (nothing to do with the script here, except whether to write it...): It's generally unwise to create a local branch name just because some remote-tracking name exists locally. The remote-tracking names keep getting updated by each `git fetch`, but the local names *don't*. Unless you are actively doing your own work on a local name, don't *create* a local name unnecessarily!

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback everyone! I was trying to clone all branches for [this repo](https://github.com/lawwantsin/webpack-course). When I click the clone button I get this as the copied link: ```https://github.com/lawwantsin/webpack-course.git``` Don't know why I thought it had the ```www```. @torek is it a bad idea to create a profile tool for a finished repo like this? Its for a course I'm starting for learning more about webpack

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "profile tool". Git repositories are really all about *commits*, with branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and any other names you create or find, just being ways to identify some *particular* commit. Branch names have the special feature that `git checkout` will get you "on" that branch (not JUST get you the commit: you can `git checkout` any commit as a *detached* HEAD, but only a branch name can be an *attached* HEAD). When "on" a branch, a *new* commit changes the name to point *to* that new commit, automatically.

Comment: Sorry should have clarified: zsh or bash profile tool. After what you explained about git though I now understand that it has very niche use. @torek thanks for the quick reply and info about git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zsh` can do regular expression matching itself; there's no need to use `sed`:

```
cloneAllBranches () { 
  repoName=$1

  git clone "$repoName"

  regex='^https?://www\.github\.com/([-_[:alnum:]])+/([-_[:alnum:]]+)\.git$'
  [[ $repoName =~ $regex ]] || return

  dirName=$match[2]  # arrays are 1-indexed in zsh

  ...
}
```